# How to pass parameters to server in android

Tags: android, json, webserver

I have a URL of this format `"http://testserver.com/Test/login!checkUser.cc?email=testemail123@gmail.com"` . I want to send this to server and inturn i will get a response of Json format `"[{"status":"0"}]"`. How to achieve this in android.

Comment: Hi, i searched, but i m nt getting exact way .. i am very new to this web part. though it may look silly for you but not for me. kindly provide me answer, it will be really helpful..

Answer (score 1):

You would make use of an `HttpClient` and other `Http*` classes.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://testserver.com/Test/login!checkUser.cc?email=testemail123@gmail.com");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

// Check if server response is valid
StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
if (status.getStatusCode() != 200) {
   throw new IOException("Invalid response from server [" + status.toString() + "]");
                    }

// Pull content stream from response
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   builder.append(line);
                    }

//return result from buffered stream
String dataAsString = builder.toString();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(dataAsString);
```